# How do I stop Mozilla telemetry?

Tags: firefox, privacy

My Firefox install on my desktop is repeatedly trying to connect to "https://incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org".  That site *appears* like it's probably legit (my only question is that it appears to be hosted on AWS, but I suppose it's possible Mozilla uses them).  The problem is that those IP addresses are blacklisted through our corporate AV/AM vendor.  The end result is that I'm generating security alerts all day long...

While I could escalate this with the vendor, I'd like to just kill the telemetry in Firefox anyways for privacy reasons.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a telemetry option in the settings screens and Google is failing me too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go to `Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Data Choices` you can untick the the options there.
[image: Firefox telemetry location]

Comment: Ah, excellent.  The lack of the telemetry keyword was enough for me to totally miss those options!

Answer (score 5):

Or... go to about:config in Firefox and search for "telemetry" and set `toolkit.telemetry.server` to 0.0.0.0, or some other non-existent IP. Also be sure to disable `toolkit.telemetry.unified`, `toolkit.telemetry.enabled` and `toolkit.telemetry.archive.enabled`. When I say disable a setting, I mean set it to **False**.

Enjoy assurance you're not being spied on by companies! Except if you use Windows 10...

Comment: See also [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1197144) on the support forum.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime (Firefox 90 is the current version at this point in time) these settings have moved to `Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Firefox Data Collection and Use`.

Alternatively you can reach these settings by entering `about:preferences#privacy` in the URL bar.

[image: Screenshot]